# Adding Skin to Edge Creates Strange Anomaly

Tags: edges

I added a skin to the edge of my object in order to thicken it. It worked great but it creates a strange effect in places. Here's an image:

[image]

It looks like crevice shadows or something even though all of the vertices are on the same plane. How do I get rid of that?

File in question:
[image]

Comment: it looks like the faces that are generated by the Skin modifiers are overlapping, maybe share your object to see if we can create the same shape without overlapping

Comment: Sure! But I'm a newbie so should I share the blender file or export to something else? How should I share the object?

Comment: Use https://blend-exchange.com/ (read the instructions), or use a platform like workupload

Comment: Shared the file. Added the link to the bottom of my post.

Comment: These are overlapping vertices as I said, what is the object that you are trying to achieve?

Comment: I guess I don't understand how they are overlapping. I just want the orange area to be solid. As you saw, there are two objects. The orange one is in front of the other and acts like a border. My plan is to bring that into a mobile app using swift via Xcode. In the app, I will put an image on the rear object but the irage border will be on top of that. Am I making any sense?

Comment: They are overlapping because it's like if you do the extrusion of an edge, at one point the faces will overlap, I'm not there's any other way to fix it than apply the modifier and correct the topology

Comment: Thanks @moonboots. I'm definitely out of my depth here. How do I "correct the topology"?

Comment: Do you have a reference image of the object that you'retrying to achieve, with the Skin modifier I'm afraid you'll have overlapping faces, you could instead extrude and scale down the shape